# Is there a way to get song play counts/recently played songs on Android?

Tags: android, media

I'm wondering if there's any way to access the top played/recently played songs, or play counts for songs on Android? I've had a look at getting information from a content resolver using the `MediaStore`, but I haven't found anything. There's a lot in there though, so I may have missed something. I've also looked at `MediaMetadataRetriever`, but I can't see anything there either. Looking at Wikipedia shows that ID3v2 tags can contain a play counter, but is this accessible through Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is a link](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/f75e3a4d2a099bd0) that says it should be possible using the id3 tag library.

The `FrameBodyPCNT` is the play counter class you need use from the id3 tag library.

Comment: I didn't actually get a chance to test this, but I've accepted as it seems that it would work, and for pointing out the name of the relevant field.

Answer (score 1):

As a partial answer, I did have an idea while I was playing around with this, to use the `lastModified()` method (as I was going through all the songs as `File`s anyway). This functionality actually got scrapped in the end, so I didn't test it, but using `lastModified()` and taking those songs with the highest value should give you the latest played/added songs (as I'm guessing the ID3 tags would be slightly altered with each play, especially as there is the play counter).

However, I'm going to wait a little longer to see if anyone else comes up with something.

Comment: Hi, i'm also looking for a way to count each play of a song so i can populate a list with "most played songs". Did you found a way for achieving this?

Comment: @Vince I didn't I'm afraid; we didn't go ahead with that feature so I didn't look into that kind of thing. Good luck!